# How to do conditional validation with FluentValidation

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to make a custom validation with FluentValidation which depends on another property on my object.

`pos.Menge` is a decimal, as well as `pos.Preis`

```
RuleFor(pos => pos)
.Custom((pos, context) =>
{
    if(pos.Menge < 10000 && MathExtensions.GetDecimalPlaces(pos.Preis) > 2)
    {
        context.AddFailure(new ValidationFailure(nameof(pos.Preis), "Bei Mengen unter 10000 darf der Preis maximal 2 Nachkommastellen haben."));
    }
    else if(pos.Menge >= 10000 && MathExtensions.GetDecimalPlaces(pos.Preis) > 4)
    {
        context.AddFailure(new ValidationFailure(nameof(pos.Preis), "Der Preis darf maximal 4 Nachkommastellen haben."));
    }
});
```

This validation works when submitting a form. However, the validation message is not shown for my property. It is only visible within the ValidationSummary. Also the validation does not become triggered when changing the value. Only OnSubmit.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of conditionally applying a validation rule for what looks like a scale precision check, the following LINQPad example may suit. I'm using scale precision to perform your `MathExtensions.GetDecimalPlaces(pos.Preis)` check and `When` to determine when to apply that rule based on the value of another property.

```
void Main()
{
    var validator = new FooValidator();

    Console.WriteLine(validator.Validate(new Foo() { Bar = 1000.001m, Baz = 1 }).Errors?.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
    Console.WriteLine(validator.Validate(new Foo() { Bar = 1000.00001m, Baz = 10001 }).Errors?.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
}

public class Foo
{
    public decimal Bar { get; set; }
    public decimal Baz { get; set; }
}

public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<Foo>
{
    public FooValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(foo => foo.Bar).ScalePrecision(2, int.MaxValue).WithMessage("Bei Mengen unter 10000 darf der Preis maximal 2 Nachkommastellen haben.").When(foo => foo.Baz < 10000);
        RuleFor(foo => foo.Bar).ScalePrecision(4, int.MaxValue).WithMessage("Der Preis darf maximal 4 Nachkommastellen haben.").When(foo => foo.Baz >= 10000);
    }
}
```

[image]

I don't know the full use case so YMMV. A `Custom` rule [will not work](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#clientside-validation) with client side validation out of the box, nor will scale precision but it can be supported if you write your own adapter. I'm not entirely sure that a populated model state will play ball either, but the above is where I would start; best results I have found for support is to use custom validators when there are no other options.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of this When method. It makes everything much easier.

Comment: It does, but keep in mind `When` does not work client side.